# "tensor products of elliptic curves"

Tags: reference-request, tensor-products, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about elliptic curves (EC) and abelian varieties. The question is motivated by EC cryptography.

**Question.** Suppose I have two elliptic curves $E/k$ and $E'/k$. Is there an abelian variety $T/k$ such that for any extension $K/k$, $T(K)\simeq E(K)\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}E'(K)$.

These isomorphisms would ideally be compatible with morphisms of extensions i.e. functorial in the appropriate sense. If it helps: $k$ will be a finite field and $E\simeq E'$ (i.e. they are isomorphic over $\overline{k}$).

If the answer is yes, where can I read about this?

Comment: Do you really mean tensor product? As group, $E(K)$ is direct sum of at most two cyclics.

Comment: @Lubin I do mean tensor products. In applications I would have $E=E'$.

Comment: Well, you’ll have to do some persuading to convince me that the tensor product of these two groups will be at all interesting.

Comment: @Lubin I basically want to use the $n$-torsion of $T$ as a model for the tensor product of the $n$-torsions of $E$ and $E'$, particularly when $n$ is prime and $E\simeq E'$. The $n$-torsion of a curve supports bilinear maps such as the Weil pairing $e_n$. I basically want to move away from pairings (bilinear maps) to $\Bbb{Z}$-linear maps $$ T[n] \to E[n]\otimes E'[n] \xrightarrow{~e_n~}\mu_n(\overline{k}).$$ Where $E[n]$ represents the $n$ torsion of $E$ and similarly for $T$ (if it exists).

Comment: All right, well, good luck to you.